# afterstep handler not being called in ItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an issue with my writer where the `afterStep()` is not being called:

```
public class MyWriter implements ItemStreamWriter<MyDTO>, StepExecutionListener {


    private FlatFileItemWriter<MyDTO> delegate;

    private Resource resource;

    public void setDelegate(final FlatFileItemWriter<MyDTO> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        delegate.setResource(resource);
    }


    public void setResource(final Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.setResource(resource);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyDTO> items) throws Exception {
        delegate.write(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // do nothing
        return null;
    }
```

I have step scoped the bean also:

```
 @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamWriter<MyDTO> itemWriter() {

        DelimitedLineAggregator<MyDTO> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyDTO> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames(new String[]{"test"});

        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor);

        MyWriter writer = new MyWriter();

        FlatFileItemWriter<MyDTO> flatFileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        flatFileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        flatFileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
        flatFileItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

        writer.setDelegate(flatFileItemWriter);
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getRequestOutputResource(blah)));

        return writer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the writer bean is `ItemStreamWriter`, so the step scoped proxy bean that Spring Batch creates will not be seen as a `StepExecutionListener`. You need to register your writer as a step execution listener.

As a side note, your class is doing two things (it's a writer and a listener at the same time). Polymorphism is a good idea for some use cases, but in your case, I would separate each logic in its own class for more clarity and to avoid proxying confusions.

Comment: Not exactly sure of the change required. How to register the writer as step execution listener ? Any example please ?

Comment: In your step definition, you do something like: `.writer(myWriter()).listener(myWriter())`. You might need to cast the writer to `StepExecutionListener` for this to work. But again, I would separate the writer logic from the listener logic in different classes and make each thing do one thing and do it well, because [so much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things.](https://twitter.com/codewisdom/status/1006219510741983232).

Comment: I tried `.listener((StepExecutionLister) myWriter)` which did not work with cannot cast exception. I need to put the reference of the `resource` in my `ItemWriter` class in the `executionContext` for the next step so I need the afterstep logic in the same class.

Comment: That's not an issue, you are injecting the resource in the writer, so you can inject it in a separate listener as well and have a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: can you pls help with an example with providing the resource as in my case ?